# I want to read a text file into a variable and insert that variable in SQL Server using Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have created below code

```
$a = Get-Content sample_Cntl.TXT
$a
$e= $a.Substring(84,5)
$e
$server=server_name
$db=database_name

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('4070','12','0.0','0.0',$e,'6.31');" -ServerInstance $server -Database $db
```

i want to insert the $e along with other values in database table, but it is all getting wrong.

what i'm getting is $a value as

..........................................................................201703...06.31

i want to get $e=201703 and insert it into table.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: what is your error? Explain your problem in detail

Answer (score 0):

`$e` is either an array or somehow not holding an appropriate data item for your `INSERT` statement. You probably need to iterate through the array and provide a single value at a time. Try something like this:

```
$a = Get-Content sample_Cntl.TXT
$e= $a.Substring(84,5)
$server=server_name
$db=database_name
foreach($f in $e){
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('4070','12','0.0','0.0',$f,'6.31');" -ServerInstance $server -Database $db
}
```